# How can I set default screen tkinter not full screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set default tkinter screen and not full screen in tkinter.Thank you

Comment: You can specify the window size with .geometry() like so: w = Tk(); w.geometry("500x300") // width is 500 and height is 300

Comment: The default isn't full screen. If you create a blank window is it coming up full screen? How are you running your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root.geometry("500x100") #Width x Height
```

Use this code to change your Tkinter screen size. Here `root` is the main window, `geometry()` is the function used to change screen size. `500` is the width and `100` is the height

Answer (score 0):

its very easy you just need to set the with and heigth of the window by

```
root.geometry("400x900") # this .geometry() takes a string in the form of width x heigth
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various arguments for your Tkinter window :

```py
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

Changing it to False will disable fullscreen mode, True will activate it

```py
window.geometry("1400x700")
```

You can set the default size of your GUI with this, but the user will be able to resize it classically

```py
window.minsize(200, 200)
```

This one will set the minimum size of your GUI, past it, the user will not be able to reduce the window any further. If you set it to the size of your window, you disable the resizing.